# Inline eco templates with coffeescript and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, eco

Is it possible to use `eco.render` inside rails coffeescript file?

`JST` become availabel only after we include template, so maybe we can require some file(inside application.js) to make `eco` available

Comment: Any chance you've figured this out?